# How to make FailureResolutionAware work for custom Gradle exceptions?

Tags: gradle

I just found out about Gradle's `FailureResolutionAware` which custom exceptions can implement to provide additional guidance to the user about how to resolve a build error.

I just can't get it to work for me... I have an exception implementing the interface, but it doesn't seem to get picked up by the `BuildExceptionReporter` (i.e. the method `appendResolution()` is never called.

Any idea on that? Here's my custom exception btw:

```
public class SomeFancyException extends GradleException implements FailureResolutionAware {
    public SomeFancyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void appendResolution(StyledTextOutput output, BuildClientMetaData clientMetaData) {
        output.text("Here is some fancy help for you!");
    }
}
```

Any help highly appreciated :-)

Comment: You are aware that `FailureResolutionAware` is an internal class that is not under the guarantees of backward or forward compatibility? Meaning your build can break at any time if you use this with different Gradle versions.

Comment: You could set a breakpoint in the `BuildExceptionReporter` and have a look why it does not work.

Comment: Hmm, I was semi-aware of that. I noticed it, but you're right in your warning. Cheers for the hint!
Still would love to make it work for some experiment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I have seen from a 10 minutes debugging session, all exceptions you throw are catched and wrapped in other exceptions. For example when you throw it during task execution, in a `TaskExecutionException` or if you throw it directly in the script or during configuration of a task, in a `GradleScriptException`. This exception then is again wrapped in a `LocationAwareException`. This `LocationAwareException` is a `FailureResolutionAware` and even delegates the `appendResolution` call to its cause if it is also a `FailureResolutionAware`. But the other exceptions that are between `LocationAwareException` and your exception do not delegate this call further. So I'd say this is a purely internal class that you should not and cannot use with your own exceptions.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the analysis!
Kinda sad though, I totally love such concepts (think Spring Boot's `FailureAnalyzer`).
Maybe something to bring up to the Gradle folks...

Comment: Btw. what is wrong with simply setting the Exception message to contain all information you want to show to the user? The Exception message is always presented and you can also include line breaks to improve readability.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it as such, but the failure output is `What went wrong`, `Where` and `Try`, where I think it would just make sense to be able to append something to the `Try` part if a solution can be presented to the user.
I think it's a great concept to present a failure to the user like that and would love to stay consistent with what is already there.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see.